# grouping condition in solr

Tags: solr, grouping

here is the product format i have

```
<doc>
    <str name="productname">ipad</str>
    <str name="sku">1524856</str>
    <str name="store">apple.com</str>
</doc> 
<doc>
    <str name="productname">ipad</str>
    <str name="sku">1524856</str>
    <str name="store">apple.com</str>
</doc> 
<doc>
    <str name="productname">ipad</str>
    <str name="sku">1524856</str>
    <str name="store">buy.com</str>
</doc> 
<doc>
    <str name="productname">ipad</str>
    <str name="sku">1524856</str>
    <str name="store">amazon.com</str>
</doc> 
<doc>
    <str name="productname">ipad</str>
    <str name="sku">1524856</str>
    <str name="store">amazon.com</str>
</doc> 
<doc>
    <str name="productname">ipad</str>
    <str name="sku">1524856</str>
    <str name="store">ebay.com</str>
</doc>
```

i have to group it with sku so i write it as

```
http://**********/?q=ipad&wt=xml&group=true&group.field=upc&group.ngroups=true
```

and in my output is

```
<result name="doclist" numFound="6" start="0">
<doc>
    <str name="productname">ipad</str>
    <str name="sku">1524856</str>
    <str name="store">apple.com</str>
</doc>
```

but i want to group with store name too. if more than one product in a store with same sku it should take only one store

my o/p should be like this(numfound=4 instead of 6)

```
<result name="doclist" numFound="4" start="0">
<doc>
    <str name="productname">ipad</str>
    <str name="sku">1524856</str>
    <str name="store">apple.com</str>
</doc>
```

Comment: Try adding store also in the group field. For example: **group.field=productname+store**

Comment: its not working. its showing error in the query

Comment: check `http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing#Request_Parameters`

Comment: i checked that before but cant able to figure out which one suits my need

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by adding 'group.limit=100000' this displays all doc list in the group that matched the condition from there i grouped it uniquely using php